# Soft Question: Linear Algebra Textbook to serve as a good foundation for Functional Analysis?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question

I want recommendations for an advanced linear algebra textbook that focuses on theory  and provides adept background to support an advanced undergraduate or beginning graduate course  Functional Analysis (using Kreyszig's book). Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure how advanced you want, but Halmos's *Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces* was written basically for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try *Linear Algebra and its Applications* by Peter Lax.